# Delayed_Job executing rake not redirecting output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I have a class which is currently being executed via delayed job. One of the tasks is to execute "rake spec" and redirect the output.

I do this as such:

```
class Executor
  def execute_command(cmd, &block)
    STDOUT.sync = true # That's all it takes...
    IO.popen(cmd + " 2>&1") do |pipe| # Redirection is performed using operators
      pipe.sync = true
      while str = pipe.gets
      block.call str # This is synchronous!
      end
    end

    return $?.success?
  end
end
```

However, none of the output appears and it doesn't even aware to execute the unit tests correctly.

Capistrano works and it works on OSX. My server is Ubuntu running Passenger.

Anyone have any ideas why the output wouldn't be redirecting?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 2):

Try without the STDFDES redirection on cmd 
here is what i used and what i get.

```
class Executor
  def execute_command(cmd, &block)
    STDOUT.sync = true # That's all it takes...
    IO.popen(cmd) do |pipe| # Redirection is performed using operators
      pipe.sync = true
      while str = pipe.gets
       block.call str # This is synchronous!
      end
    end

    return $?.success?
  end
end
```

Tested with:

```
ex = Executor.new
ex.execute_command "ps aux" do |str|
   p str
end
```

result:

> "USER             PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED
>   TIME COMMAND\n" "mitch            423   3.4  1.0  2750692 159552   ?? 
>   S    23Apr12  19:41.59 /Users/mitch/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm
>   -psn_0_40970\n" "_windowserver     90   3.1  1.8  3395124 301576   ??  Ss   20Apr12  75:19.86
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/WindowServer
>   -daemon\n" "mitch          78896   2.0  0.8  1067248 136088   ??  R    Thu03PM  37:46.59 /Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotify
>   -psn_0_4900012\n" "mitch            436   1.8  1.0  1063952 169320   ??  S    23Apr12 100:23.87
>   /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype -psn_0_90134\n"